# Zend_Controller_Action_Exception not showing a 404 page

Tags: zend-framework, error-handling, zend-controller

I'm trying to get Zend to throw a 404 error if an array  contains less than 10 elements, but it is currently just sending me a generic "Error" page. I know the 404 exception is configured properly as they work elsewhere in the site so it must be a problem with my parameters or something...

I've tried formatting this several different ways and I've checked the Zend API to make sure the parameters I'm passing are OK and they seem to be correct, but I must be doing something wrong.

My code is currently as follows:

```
$properties = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)

if (count($properties) < 10){
    throw new Zend_Controller_Action_Exception('Page does not exist.', 404);
}
$this->view->rows = $properties; 
$this->callRender();
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [ErrorHandler plugin docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.plugins.html#zend.controller.plugins.standard.errorhandler) and how it [works within the MVC](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.exceptions.html). You'll notice that by default the errorHandler works as `postDispatch()` plugin. The activity you are trying describe as '404' is completely outside of the dispatch loop so it is handled as any other program error.

I don't have any code for you but I'm pretty sure you can find a usable answer in these 2 references.